# Why is my code NOT vulnerable to SQL injection?

Tags: php, sql-injection

Trying to make a simple PHP app which is vulnerable to SQL injection.
If the user/pass is correct, it let's me sign in, if not, it doesn't.
However, when I try any of these:

```
' OR '1' = '1

' OR '1'='1

' OR '1' = '1' --
```

the following error message appears:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given on line 14
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given on line 15

I have tried to inject in both fields and using valid username/injection and injection/valid password combinations too, but to no avail.
Could someone please point the problem out? Thanks. Code:

```
<!-- index.php -->

<?php
include("config.php");
session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if(isset($_POST["sbm"])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password']; 
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count == 1) {
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
        header("location: welcome.php");
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method = "post">
        <label>Username</label><input type = "text" name = "username"/><br /><br />
        <label>Password</label><input type = "password" name = "password"/><br/><br />
        <input type = "submit" value = "Login" name="sbm"/><br />
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<!-- config.php -->

<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'db');
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
?>

<!-- welcome.php -->

<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classical way of SQL injection:

```
Query: SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'
```

insert the following for username and password values:

$username = 1' or '1' = '1 
and
$password = 1' or '1' = '1.

The Query then reads:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='1' OR '1' = '1' AND password='1' OR '1' = '1'
```

the Query returns a value (or values) because the condition is always true (OR 1=1).

Comment: thanks for the hint, this worked perfectly fine!

also, thanks for all participants in the thread for their time and suggestions.